# issue with the simple if condition in javascript with string

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logic

So something very strange,below are the alert values:

- consumerSupportEditableRole = true
- superAdminRole = false
- combinedRole = false

However the strange thing is that the the alert on the combinedRole give me consumerSupport/ConsumerContact/GetEmailLog. So it is for some ungodly reason going in the if block. I would expect it to 
go to the else block and the alert should spit Implementation/Organization/GetEmailLog

```
var consumerSupportEditableRole = '@(Roles.IsUserInRole("Consumer Support Editable") ? "true" : "false")';
var superAdminRole = '@(Roles.IsUserInRole("Super Admin") ? "false" : "true")';
var combinedRole = consumerSupportEditableRole && superAdminRole
alert("consumerSupportEditableRole: " + consumerSupportEditableRole);
alert("superAdminRole: " + superAdminRole);
alert("superAdminRole && consumerSupportEditableRole: " + combinedRole);
if (combinedRole)
{
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetEmailLog", "ConsumerContact", new { Area = "ConsumerSupport" })';
}
else
{
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetEmailLog", "Organization", new { Area = "Implementation" })';
}
```

Comment: Don't use strings to hold boolean values, and you will be sweet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove quotes, you get not booleans in JS, but strings

```
var consumerSupportEditableRole = @(Roles.IsUserInRole("Consumer Support Editable") ? "true" : "false");
var superAdminRole = @(Roles.IsUserInRole("Super Admin") ? "false" : "true");
var combinedRole = consumerSupportEditableRole && superAdminRole
alert("consumerSupportEditableRole: " + consumerSupportEditableRole);
alert("superAdminRole: " + superAdminRole);
alert("superAdminRole && consumerSupportEditableRole: " + combinedRole);
if (combinedRole)
{
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetEmailLog", "ConsumerContact", new { Area = "ConsumerSupport" })';
}
else
{
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetEmailLog", "Organization", new { Area = "Implementation" })';
}
```

Comment: `'true'` is not the same as `true`

Comment: @rpadovani - he did, as that is serverside code, no longer outputted inside quotes, hence removed.

Comment: @rpadovani you don't need to. Seems like it's C# generates JS code, in C# `"true"` and `"false"` is string i guess, but qoutes will not prints, so in JS it becomes boolean.

Answer (score 3):

You're setting `consumerSupportEditableRole` and `superAdminRole` to strings, not booleans.  So `combinedRole` is actually:

```
var combinedRole = "true" && "false";
```

which makes it `"false"`, which is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).